# A probabilistic question using basic formulas

Tags: probability, time-series

I would like to understand a probabilistic result, but I would like to understand what is the fundamental theorems(Law of Total Probability, Bayes'theorem etc) underlying the procedure.

First, I have a two scenarios for each time $t:\,\,$ $S_t = 1,2$ and a history $\Omega_t = \{y_t, y_{t-1}, ....\}$.

Transition between regimes is governed by a Markov chain:
\begin{equation}\label{MCH1}
    \mbox{Pr} (s_t = j \, | \, s_{t-1} = i, s_{t-2} = k, \cdots, \underbrace{y_{t-1}, y_{t-2}, \cdots  }_{\Omega_{t-1}}) = p_{ij}, \,\,\, i, j = 1,2
\end{equation}

My goal is to understand the procedure of the two formulas. The first seems to be more easy:

1- $\operatorname{Pr}\left(s_{0}=1 \mid \Omega_{0}\right)=\frac{p_{21}}{p_{21}+p_{12}}, \,\, t = 0$

2- $\operatorname{Pr}\left(s_{t}=j \mid \Omega_{t-1}\right)=p_{1 j} \operatorname{Pr}\left(s_{t-1}=1 \mid \Omega_{t-1}\right)+p_{2 j} \operatorname{Pr}\left(s_{t-1}=2 \mid \Omega_{t-1}\right)$

Relating the first, I tryed the classic conditional probabily formula:
$$ \operatorname{Pr}\left(s_{0}=1 \mid \Omega_{0}\right)=\frac{ \mbox{Pr}([s_0 = 1] \cap [\Omega_0])  }{ \mbox{Pr}(\Omega_0) } \underbrace{=}_{?} \frac{p_{21}}{p_{21}+p_{12}}  $$

About the second formula, I have

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Pr}\left(s_{t}=j \mid \Omega_{t-1}\right)&=p_{1 j} \operatorname{Pr}\left(s_{t-1}=1 \mid \Omega_{t-1}\right)+p_{2 j} \operatorname{Pr}\left(s_{t-1}=2 \mid \Omega_{t-1}\right)\\
&= \operatorname{Pr}\left(s_{t}=j \mid s_{t-1}= 1, \Omega_{t-1}\right) \operatorname{Pr}\left(s_{t-1}=1 \mid \Omega_{t-1}\right) + \operatorname{Pr}\left(s_{t}=j \mid s_{t-1}= 2, \Omega_{t-1}\right) \operatorname{Pr}\left(s_{t-1}=2 \mid \Omega_{t-1}\right)
\end{align}

But I can't finish the demo in a rigorous way.

Some explicative deduction?

**UPDATE**

I need to add an information:

$$y_{t} = m_{s_t} + \varepsilon_{t}, \quad \varepsilon_{t} \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$$

where $m_{s_t} = m_1 > 0 $ if $s_t = 1$ and $m_{s_t} = m_2 < 0 $ if $s_t = 2$

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/548876/a-probabilistic-question-using-basic-formulas